# Is there a way to see linux logon users?

Tags: linux, ssh

I can see the logon users from rdp using rdpy-rdpscreenshot.py etc. My question is, is there a way to see the logon users from a Linux OS, without signing in?
I tried to use rdpy-vncclient.py but it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to log in and list users for example using `users`

Comment: i can see logon users fom rdp windows without signing in,so are u sure?no way?vnc screenshot.py in python something?

Comment: once you put tag `ssh`, no there is no way to see that unless you log in to ssh. I don't know about other ways, but I hope it is not possible. It is generally bad idea to give possible attacker any information about the system. What are you trying to solve by this?

Comment: Depending on the login manager, you may be able to see some over XDMCP.